# How to Check that Google Analytics is Successfully installed on every single page of a website

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Is there any possible way/ method to check that google analytics code is installed on all the pages of a website?

Please recommend me so, that I can fix that up.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a crawler to go through your sitemap.xml (provided you have one, *damn, you should have*) and crawl through every link provided there and check for ga() being available as a function. A simple script would be:

```
if(typeof(ga) === 'function' || ga instanceof Function) {
   return true;
   // handles control to the next check
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [this tool](http://www.gachecker.com/). I used it to crawl my website, and the result was positive, for over 1500 pages it has crawled in the time I wrote this answer.

Comment: It is good but, now working on the product pages or categorie pages of ecommerce.